# Google Map Initialize Script with Vue

Tags: google-maps-api-3, vuejs3, bootstrap-vue

My project have a main.ts for initialize bootstrap and vue app, I also have many .vue file, some .vue files will use google map.

I have a problem that the following script is google suggested for initialize the map, where should I put?

```
<script>
  (g=>{var h,a,k,p="The Google Maps JavaScript API",c="google",l="importLibrary",q="__ib__",m=document,b=window;b=b[c]||(b[c]={});var d=b.maps||(b.maps={}),r=new Set,e=new URLSearchParams,u=()=>h||(h=new Promise(async(f,n)=>{await (a=m.createElement("script"));e.set("libraries",[...r]+"");for(k in g)e.set(k.replace(/[A-Z]/g,t=>"_"+t[0].toLowerCase()),g[k]);e.set("callback",c+".maps."+q);a.src=`https://maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?`+e;d[q]=f;a.onerror=()=>h=n(Error(p+" could not load."));a.nonce=m.querySelector("script[nonce]")?.nonce||"";m.head.append(a)}));d[l]?console.warn(p+" only loads once. Ignoring:",g):d[l]=(f,...n)=>r.add(f)&&u().then(()=>d[l](f,...n))})({
    key: "YOUR_API_KEY_HERE",
    // Add other bootstrap parameters as needed, using camel case.
    // Use the 'v' parameter to indicate the version to load (alpha, beta, weekly, etc.)
  });
</script>
```